# How do people understand astromech droids?

Tags: star-wars, droids

In all the Star Wars movies, R2D2 just boops and beeps his way around. And everyone understands him perfectly, though he is obviously *not* speaking Basic.

How do people understand him - is there like an astromech language? If so, then would one have to learn it, or is it comprised of feelings and emotions (expressed in beeps), essentially making a tonal language?

If I may be permitted to use an example from the prequels without too many lynch mobs forming, Anakin Skywalker converses frequently with Artoo while in the Naboo fighter, but he couldn't have had much schooling at the age of eleven, especially because he was a slave.

So how would people, Anakin especially, be able to understand astromechs?

Comment: Funny randomness: After clicking "Post Question", SE asked me if I was a robot. The irony. :)

Comment: Well... are you?

Comment: If I recall corerclty, there's a boops-and-beeps-to-text translator in the fighters. I believe that's also how Luke talks to Artoo. I'll leave that as a comment since I don't have anything to back this up.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff That's an interesting idea, and it sounds like you could be onto something. Secondly, I will have you know that I am merely a very life-like script. Anything I say is not to be trusted. Trust me. ;)

Comment: @LoïcWolff You're correct. I recently rewatched *Empire*, and when after they leave Hoth, Luke and R2 are chatting with Luke reading R2's responses off a screen in the cockpit.

Comment: It's just the same as how I can usually get a general understanding of what my cat is saying to me... even though i don't speak `Catonesse`.

Comment: Luke can also understand R2 outside of the ship. The reason for the translator in starships is that there is no sound in space... or at least that was my theory... nevermind that starwars does apparently have sound in space.

Comment: @LoïcWolff - Yes and the text was in English despite the deathstar text all being in some alien language(Coruscanti if memory serves).

Comment: @aslum: R2 does, however, send his beeps and bloops to Luke over his headset, or the ship speakers.

Comment: @PeterDC - blieep bleep blooooop beeeep

Comment: @Chad Nope, it was in the same non-English text as the other screens with see in the movies.

Comment: @Keen no because the audience could read it and Luke just responded to his questions.  I suppose it may have been changed though I admit it has been a few years since i watched it last.

Comment: It's ironic because it's far easier to build a computer that speaks to you versus a computer that understands what you are speaking.

Comment: As far as Anakin goes, the boy builds droids in his spare time.

Comment: @Chad I've posted a screenshot over in [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6262/do-we-ever-see-written-english-in-the-star-wars-films) question.

Comment: I don't think it's that surprising -- it's pretty easy to to learn morse-code, I doubt astromech is much more difficult.

Comment: R2D2 speaks perfect English.  It is just bleeped because he has such an immensely foul mouth to keep the rating at PG.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All droids speak and understand [Binary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Binary) - the language R2 uses.

In general, the tones used can convey much of the meaning.  Translators like C-3P0 have to translate for most people, though people who have spent a lot of time around droids can learn at least a little of what different sounds/phrases mean - just watching the trilogy, most people can figure out 'yes' and 'no'.

Luke especially spends a lot of time with R2, and has his X-Wing's computer terminal for R2 to 'speak' through - accompanied by the verbalizations he would make.  Luke certainly has at least a basic understanding of the language.

The rest of what Luke displays can be attributed to his knowing R2 so well - He can guess how R2 will respond, get a basic idea of the question from what he knows, and fill in the blanks intuitively.

Interestingly, the *Galaxy of Fear* young adult series featured an R2 unit with a speech module - an optional component which allowed them to speak in Basic.

Comment: The prequels ruined R2D2 for me. Once I found out that this droid had been around humans for DECADES and never had a friggin' speech module installed, I totally lost all faith in George Lucas. Well, ok, lots of other things about the prequels made me lose faith too. But STILL.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: If you were as superior in all ways (except handling those damnable stairs) to the meatbags around you, would YOU want to make it easier to talk to them?

Comment: @Jeff, there's a scene in one of the prequels that shows R2 handling stairs... with rockets! He truly is the superior being.

Comment: @JohnSensebe: I never said R2 *can't* handle stairs, just that humans are superior to him in handling them.  Legs > burning rocket fuel when handling stairs.

Comment: @Jeff, but rockets *look* cooler.

Comment: Sonified Droid Binary has been proposed IRL,too: https://twitter.com/invis_insight/status/955299434354692098

Answer (score 31):

I'm not a Star Wars expert, but it certainly seems to me that people *don't* generally understand the astromechs. Generally, C3PO has to translate for R2D2 - the only time in the original films that Luke understands R2 without his help is when he's in his X-Wing, and it's clearly shown that R2's beeps are being translated on the screen of Luke's ship.

Answer (score 13):

As you can see from the first deleted scene from Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith, the simple answer is that humans don't generally understand Artoo although they may have a basic understanding of "spoken Droid". Note that while Anakin is able to reproduce the sounds perfectly, his comprehension is limited and he is relying on the communicator to provide a textual translation.

> **Anakin:** *Artoo, where are they holding the Chancellor?*
>
> **Artoo:** [Beeps]
>
> **Anakin:** *No text*
>
> [Anakin hits the communicator]
>
> [Artoo beeps]
>
> **Anakin:** *It's broken. Can you understand what he's saying?*
>
> **Obi-Wan:** *I'm not a protocol droid*
>
> **Anakin:** *I'm pretty sure that beep* [he perfectly reproduces Artoo's "speech"] *is down.*

You will also wish to note that this is exactly the same way that [Luke communicates with Artoo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition) in the cockpit of their X-Wing, via a speech-to-text app.

---

"*Most people*" don't speak droidspeak. Only those that work around droids bother to learn it, and even then inexpertly.

Notable characters who can understand droid (without a translator device) are;

### Luke (in his later years)

> “Artoo?” he asked, brightening, and a moment later the blue-and-white
> astromech rolled into view, chirping and whistling at length.
>
> “Yes,” Luke said. Decades of missions with R2-D2 had left him
> reasonably fluent in droidspeak, but the astromech’s list of
> accusations was both lengthy and highly specific. “No, I—yeah, it’s
> true.”
>
> R2-D2 squawked derisively.
>
> “Hey, sacred island,” Luke said. “Watch the language.”
>
> <sub><sup>[*The Last Jedi: Official Novelisation*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

### Rey

> To most people, the beeping would have sounded like mechanical
> gibberish. But Rey was good with technology and had studied the
> communication patterns of droids. And that droid was especially
> eloquent—particularly in his choice of insults toward the Teedo.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens - Rey's Story](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey%27s_Story)</sup></sub>

### Poe

> BB-8, secure in the astromech socket behind the cockpit of Poe’s X-wing, burbled a question. Plugged into the fighter, the droid’s binary-speak was automatically decoded and displayed on the console, but Poe didn’t actually need to read the translation to understand what the droid was asking.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Before the Awakening](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Before_the_Awakening)</sup></sub>

Comment: Luke also talks to R2 on Dagobah, without the translator.  Also, I have a hard time believing that the sound effects are genuine.  It's just ridiculous.  But that didn't stop Lucas from doing all the other ridiculous crap he did in the prequel trilogy, so who knows?

Comment: @WadCheber - He talks to him. There's no special reason to assume he understands him, beyond the same level of comprehension you and I have (e.g. Loud whistles = Hell No!, quiet low whistle = "I'm scared", etc).

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=p44pcTXpPOs It seems like R2 asks a question, and Luke answers "I don't know, it feels like..."

Comment: @WadCheber - If you remove Artoo's speech from the scene, it makes no difference to what Luke is saying. It's almost like he's talking to himself.

Comment: That's the other interpretation.  I like to think that they are actually communicating.

Comment: Okay, R2 DEFINITELY asks a question here, and Luke clearly understands him:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BYUqXBYA7uM

Comment: I had no idea there were deleted scenes. They are somehow even worse than what made it into the final films.

Answer (score 11):

For a direct answer as to how Anakin could understand, he worked as a mechanic for almost all of his slave life.  Of the few things he did learn, he probably learned everything there is to know about piloting and robots.  This experience would put him in the position to interact with many different droids, and the amount of exposure he had to them probably helped him learn the language (without ever really thinking that he is learning it too). Considering how a child develops language, and Anakin can clearly speak multiple languages (Basic, and Huttese which Watto speaks), it would make sense that he would learn the droid language also.

Answer (score 5):

Luke can understand R2D2 on Dagobah just before he's swallowed by the creature. He doesn't use a readout and he doesn't have C3PO with him. It must be familiarity, as Anakin also does this in the prequels.

Answer (score -1):

I think its both; you can communicate with them via text and communicators and or communicate with them through there binary language each string of beeps stands for a different word or letter. 
Think of it like people who can decode Morse code they hear beeping as letters and can understand whats being said while the rest of us just hear beep beep beep beep.
So anyone who takes the time to learn binary can talk to droids.
e.g: If uncle Owen had learned binary he wouldn't have needed to buy C3PO because he'd be able to talk to his moisture evaporators.
e.g 2: In the force awakens Rey can talk to BB-8 because she has/had to learn speaking binary to make her way on Jakku.

Ok so after typing all that out I decided to check wookieepedia,  just to make sure (check it out look for binary or droidspeak) and I'm kinda right .

Comment: Please use punctuation and proper sentences, to make your posts intelligible to others. Also, if you found an answer on Wookieepedia, please include a link in your post; answers supported by other sources (even though Wookieepedia isn't a reliable source) are received better here than those with no backup at all.