# What language is Chopper speaking?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I thought that the droid from Star Wars Rebels spoke in binary, but somehow Hera and Ezra are able to understand and interpret for it. It made sense for C3PO to understand R2 because they're both machines, and I always thought when a human character understood R2 it was because they had a console in front of them (I could be wrong, but I don't remember any instances where this wasn't the case). This doesn't seem to be the case for Chopper though. So, is Chopper not speaking in a binary encoding? Or is it somehow possible for humans to interpret binary in the Star Wars Universe?

Comment: Related, possible dupe http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/how-do-people-understand-astromech-droids or http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/is-it-possible-to-understand-what-r2-d2-is-saying

Comment: Definitely related, thanks. My question is about Chopper though. If you can confirm he speaks using binary beeps, then it is a dupe. His noises sound more like "wah-wah-wah", though, so I'm not sure if it's binary. It might be similar to the grunts the Wookies use.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude it's Binary (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Binary

According to the Binary page on [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Binary):

> Binary was language commonly spoken by droids. It consisted of a set of beeps and whistles strung together into what resembled sentences. **The C1 model utilized this form of communication**

citing *[The Rebellion Begins](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rebellion_Begins)*