# Is it ever explained why everybody seem to understand droids?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars, I find it weird that droids are not speaking the common language, but instead do beep-boops. And what is weird of that is that even then everybody seems to understand perfectly what they are saying. (or at least the protagonists)

Is it ever explained why even if droids talk in beep boops the common man seems to be capable of understanding the droid language? Like if the 'droid language' is a language just like spanish or french in our world?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do people understand astromech droids?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/how-do-people-understand-astromech-droids)

Comment: Hi Freddy, welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy stack exchange, while you're hear take a look at the [tour] and [help]. I've undeleted your question and closed it as a duplicate of the suggested question. That's because this is a perfectly good question, it just happens to have been asked before. Now your question will be a signpost to the duplicate, helping others find that information.

Comment: For further info, take a look at this [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9324/3804) on your exact situation, as well as a general [overview of duplicate](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11921/3804) questions.

Comment: Yeah I come from Arqade where a duplicate would be slapped down with downvotes. So there if you got a duplicate better to delete it. Different communities different rules I guess.

Comment: Wow, seems harsh, but if it works for them I guess? Feel free to join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) anytime.